# Nuxt pagination with query, Hydration node mismatch:

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

Try to learn Nuxt, building a webshop. Implemented a pagination for main shop page, and it functions well if I click on sites menu link to shop page and pagination buttons. Going back and forward in browser also functions. It functions to go directly to the shop site, both in dev and buid mode, but in dev I get this warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Hydration node mismatch:
- Client vnode: Symbol(v-cmt) 
- Server rendered DOM: <div class=​"grid grid-cols-1 gap-3 phone:​grid-cols-4 laptop:​grid-cols-8 justcol" data-v-7db6cc15>​<!--[--><div data-v-7db6cc15>​…​</div>​<div class=​"card text-center flex flex-col justify-between" data-v-7db6cc15 data-v-fe52aa40>​…​</div>​</div>​<div data-v-7db6cc15>​…​</div>​<div data-v-7db6cc15>​…​</div>​<div data-v-7db6cc15>​…​</div>​<!--]--></div>
```

I get the same warning if I go to a query directly (in dev mode) but in build mode it will not show up, the main query to page=1 just flash in for a millisecond and then the page went blank (http://localhost:3000/shop?page=1).

This is the shop site, template:

```
<template><div
 v-if="paginproducts"
class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-3 phone:grid-cols-4 laptop:grid-cols 
justcol"
>
 <div v-for="product in paginproducts" :key="product._id">
  <ProductCard v-if="paginproducts" :product="product" />
 </div>
 </div>
 <Pagination
  v-if="paginationlenght"
  :paginationlenght="paginationlenght"
  :paginationrow="paginationrow"
   @clicked="changePagination"
   />
   </ template>
```

This is the shop site script:

```
 <script setup>
 const route = useRoute();
 const router = useRouter();
 const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();
 const apitKey = runtimeConfig.public.apiToken;
 const paginproducts = ref(null);
 const paginationlenght = ref(null);
 const paginationrow = 4;
 const errorhandler = ref(false);

 //Fetch Products from API
 const fetchProducts = async (skip) => {
  const { data: products, error } = await useFetch(
  `${runtimeConfig.public.apiUrl}/api/content/items/Products? 
 limit=${paginationrow}&skip=${skip}`,
 {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "api-key": apitKey,
   },
 }
);
 for (let i in products._value) {
 if (products._value.data.length) {
  paginproducts.value = {};
  paginationlenght.value = {};
  paginproducts.value = products._value.data;
  paginationlenght.value = products._value.meta;
  errorhandler.value = false;
} else {
  errorhandler.value = true;
 }
}
if (error.value || errorhandler.value) {
 unwatch();
 paginproducts.value = null;
 paginationlenght.value = null;
 setTimeout(() => {
  showError({
    statusCode: 404,
    statusMessage: "Page not found.",
    data: "Generated from Category page.",
       });
     }, 1000);
   }
 };
 const changePagination = (changerow) => {
let queypage = changerow + 1;
router.push({ path: "/shop", query: { page: queypage } });
console.log("pagination");
 if (process.browser) {
 window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
  }
 };
onMounted(() => {
if (!route.query.page || route.query.page === "") {
router.replace({ path: "/shop", query: { page: "1" } });
 }
 });
  const unwatch = watch(
 () => route.query,
 () => {
  if (route.query.page !== "") {
  let skipping = parseInt(route.query.page) - 1;
  skipping = skipping * paginationrow;
  fetchProducts(skipping);
   }
  },
 { immediate: true }
 );
 </script>
```

This is the pagination component template:

```
<template>
<div v-if="totalButtons != 1" class="mt-6 w-full">
<ul
  class="flex justify-center w-auto mx-auto place-items-center flex-col 
sm:flex-row"
>
  <li class="mx-2 my-6 sm:my-auto">
    <button
      @click="onClickNumber(0)"
      :disabled="activeButton === 0"
      type="button"
      class="pagbutton"
      :class="{ active: activeButton === 0 }"
    >
      <span class="material-icons">keyboard_double_arrow_left </span>
    </button>
  </li>

  <li class="mx-2 my-6 sm:my-auto">
    <button
      @click="onClickNumber(activeButton - 1)"
      :disabled="activeButton === 0"
      type="button"
      class="pagbutton"
      :class="{ active: activeButton === 0 }"
    >
      <span class="material-icons"> chevron_left </span>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li
    v-for="(number, index) in totalButtons"
    :key="index"
    class="mx-2 my-6 sm:my-auto"
  >
    <p>
      <button
        @click="onClickNumber(index)"
        :disabled="activeButton === index"
        type="button"
        class="pagbutton buttonnumber"
        :class="{ activenumber: activeButton === index }"
      >
        {{ number }}
      </button>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="mx-2 my-6 sm:my-auto">
    <button
      @click="onClickNumber(activeButton + 1)"
      :disabled="activeButton === totalButtons - 1"
      type="button"
      class="pagbutton"
      :class="{ active: activeButton === totalButtons - 1 }"
    >
      <span class="material-icons"> chevron_right </span>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="mx-2 my-6 sm:my-auto">
    <button
      @click="onClickNumber(totalButtons - 1)"
      :disabled="activeButton === totalButtons - 1"
      type="button"
      class="pagbutton"
      :class="{ active: activeButton === totalButtons - 1 }"
    >
      <span class="material-icons">keyboard_double_arrow_right </span>
    </button>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</template>
```

This is the pagination component script:

```
<script setup>
 const route = useRoute();
 const { paginationlenght, paginationrow } = defineProps([
   "paginationlenght",
   "paginationrow",
 ]);
 const emit = defineEmits(["clicked"]);
 const activeButton = ref(0);
 let totalButtons;
 if (paginationlenght && paginationlenght.total > 0) {
   const calcButtons = paginationlenght.total % paginationrow;

  if (calcButtons === 0) {
   totalButtons = paginationlenght.total / paginationrow;
   } else {
totalButtons = (paginationlenght.total - calcButtons) / paginationrow + 
1;
   }
} else {
   totalButtons = 1;
 }
 const onClickNumber = (changenumber) => {
  activeButton.value = changenumber;
  emit("clicked", activeButton.value);
 };

 const unwatch = watch(
   async () => route.query,
   async () => {
     if (route.query.page) {
       activeButton.value = parseInt(route.query.page) - 1;
     }
   },
   { immediate: true }
 );
 </script>
```

I know that the hydration node mismatch can come from the google icons in the pagination component. I tried to set client only on them, but still same problem.

Glad for any help.
Klas

​

Comment: I partial figured it out,   route.query.page was  undefined first time in the watch (in shop page), so I set a check for it like:  if (route.query.page !== undefined) {..}. Now it functions to load   shop site direct from server without any warnings. Still same warning if I load  a query direct (server rendering) and in build mode nothing out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by my self, but it looks like it is a bug. If I do not have onMounted for the first query, i.e.

> router.replace({ path: "/shop", query: { page: "1" } })

, I get a warning message that says it probably is a bug.

Any way, the solution was to add setTimeout to the fetching function in the watch:

```
const unwatch = watch(
() => route.query.page,
() => {
 if (route.query.page !== undefined) {
  let skipping = parseInt(route.query.page, 10);
  skipping = (skipping - 1) * paginationrow;
  setTimeout(() => {         
          fetchProducts(skipping);
        }, 100);
      }
    },
    { immediate: true, deep: true }
  );
```